# get jquery ui multiselect unchecked value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a jquery UI multiselect dropdown. [Here is the link](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) I want to get unchecked value.
I have something like this for getting all selected options:

```
var optionValues = $('option:selected', this).map(function() {

                        return this.value;

                }).get();
```

But I want unchecked value.
Any idea?

Comment: $('select#yourid option:not(:selected)');

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
var notSelectedValues = $("select#id").find('option').not(':selected');
var array = notSelectedValues.map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
alert(array.join(', '))
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XqZxu/17/)

Comment: It gives me 0 length for notSelectedValues

Comment: yes, that works. Thank you. I will mark it as answer after 5 minutes.